# Rsync syntax error when run from bash script

Tags: bash, syntax, rsync

I have been working on a backup script that uses rsync to do an incremental backup.

I have tested the following rsync command manually, and it runs and completes a backup without error:

```
rsync -aAXv --delete --progress --link-dest=/backup/Uyuk/Uyuk-backup-part1/2014-02-24/ /mnt/backup/ /backup/Uyuk/Uyuk-backup-part1/2014-02-25/
```

however when I run that same command in my backup script it gives me the following error:

```
rsync: -aAXv --delete --progress --link-dest=/backup/Uyuk/Uyuk-backup-part1/2014-02-24/ /mnt/backup/ /backup/Uyuk/Uyuk-backup-part1/2014-02-25/: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1422) [client=3.0.6]
```

I ran bash -x on my script to figure out exactly what is sent to the console and here is what was printed:

```
+ rsync '-aAXv --delete --progress --link-dest=/backup/Uyuk/Uyuk-backup-part1/2014-02-24/ /mnt/backup/ /backup/Uyuk/Uyuk-backup-part1/2014-02-25/'
```

Does anyone see what is wrong? I cant find anything that would cause the syntax error.

EDIT:
Here is the actual code I have in the script, and this is a pretty large script so yes some variables are not defined here, but you get the idea.

```
mkdir -p "/backup/$HOST/$NAME/$TODAY"
#source directory
SRC="$MNT"
#link directory
LNK="/backup/$HOST/$NAME/$LAST/"
#target directory
TRG="/backup/$HOST/$NAME/$TODAY/"
#rsync options
OPT1="-aAXv --delete --progress --link-dest=$LNK"

#run the rsync command
echo "rsync $OPT1 $SRC $TRG"
rsync "$OPT1 $SRC $TRG" > /var/log/backup/backup.rsync.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Why there is single quotes around the `rsync` options in the `bash -x` output of your script? Can you include in your question the acutally statements that you use to call `rsync`?

Comment: typically a leading `+` sign and single-quoted strings are the way that `set -x` displays the line with all var expansions and string quoting, where all `"..."` are now "boiled down" to `'...'` (single-quoted strings). I think you're right that something is missing, I would guess O.P. is doing something like `rOpts="-aXV --delete..."; rsync "$rOpts"`. Hence the error msg `unknown option`,  Good luck to all.

Comment: If @shellter is right, your first stop should be [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I updated and included the code im using for running the rsync command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing your option list as a single argument, when it needs to be passed as a *list* of arguments. In general, you should use an array in `bash` to hold your arguments, in case any of them contain whitespace. Try the following:

```
mkdir -p "/backup/$HOST/$NAME/$TODAY"
#source directory
SRC="$MNT"
#link directory
LNK="/backup/$HOST/$NAME/$LAST/"
#target directory
TRG="/backup/$HOST/$NAME/$TODAY/"
#rsync options
OPTS=( "-aAXv" "--delete" "--progress" "--link-dest=$LNK" )

#run the rsync command
echo "rsync $OPT1 $SRC $TRG"
rsync "${OPTS[@]}" "$SRC" "$TRG" > /var/log/backup/backup.rsync.log 2>&1
```

An array expansion `${OPTS[@]}`, when quoted, is treated specially as a sequence of arguments, each of which is quoted individually to preserve any whitespace or special characters in the individual elements. If `arr=("a b" c d)`, then `echo "${arr[@]}"` is the same as

```
echo "a b" "c" "d"
```

rather than

```
echo "a b c d"
```

---

This will not work in a shell that doesn't support arrays, but then, arrays were invented because there wasn't a safe way (that is, without using `eval`) to handle this use case without them.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
rsync "$OPT1 $SRC $TRG"
```

passes all your intended arguments lumped together as one argument, which `rsync` doesn't know how to deal with.

Try this instead:

```
rsync ${OPT1} ${SRC} ${TRG}
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach suggested by @chepner didn't work on my Mac OS X (10.9.4), but `eval` did.

```
eval rsync "$OPT1 $SRC $TRG"
```