# rsync from bash script port failure

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

NB, the folders and ip have obv. been changed to be able to post on SO ;)

Based on the following post: [Rsync syntax error when run from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030280/rsync-syntax-error-when-run-from-bash-script)  I have constructed the following bash script to attempt to run an rsync command.. but I cannot get things to work.

By either setting the options as an array, this did not pass the port number...

```
#!/bin/bash
options=("-avz" "--delete" "--chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx" "--exclude '.idea*" "--exclude '*.git*" "--exclude 'node-sass'" "-e'ssh -p 44'")
src="/cygdrive/d/Work/site/"
trg="john@12.12.12.12:/var/node/john.site.com/"
rsync "${options[@]}" "$src" "$trg"
```

Or as passing the options as a string..

```
#!/bin/bash
options="-avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx --exclude '.idea*' --exclude '*.git*' --exclude 'node-sass' -e'ssh -p 44'"
src="/cygdrive/d/Work/site/"
trg="john@12.12.12.12:/var/node/john.site.com/"
rsync "$options" "$src" "$trg"
```

As a string is just returned an error:

> rsync: -avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx --exclude '.idea*' --exclude
>   '*.git*' --exclude 'node-sass' -e'ssh -p 44'#015: unknown option

Here is the working rsync:

```
rysnc -avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx --exclude ".idea*" --exclude "*.git*" --exclude "node-sass" -e "ssh -p 44" /cygdrive/d/Work/site/  john@12.12.12.12:/var/node/john.site.com/
```

---

NEW ATTEMPT following help from below:
I have created an ssh config entry to bypass the requirement of setting the port number into the rsync options, removed all the excludes, have entered he opts into a single quoted string and passed via herestring:

```
#!/bin/bash
opts='-avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx'
src="/cygdrive/d/Work/site/"
trg="john@mysite:/var/node/john.site.com/"
rsync <<<$opts "$src" "$trg"
```

The new command via cli looks like (and works):

```
rsync -avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx /cygdrive/d/Work/site/ john@mysite:/var/node/john.site.com/
```

But i get:

```
rsync: link_stat "/cygdrive/d/Work/site/\#015" failed: No such file or directory (2) 
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]
```

Comment: I would strongly suggest you focus on making a working rsync command before you try abstracting out the options and building the rsync command at runtime.

Comment: The rsync command works perfectly, just not in bash

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a working rsync command? What is it?

Comment: I will iost the working rsync command i current use in a macro.. give me a sec.

Comment: Done. The working rsync command is at the bottom. By the way, this is running from windows on a cygwin machine.

Comment: Passing the literal single-quotes (`"-e'ssh -p 44'"`) is obviously wrong; you don't do that in your working standalone command, so why do you do it in your script?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050, by the way, is recommended reading if you want to understand _why_ your initial attempts failed as they did.

Comment: (If you wanted to test rsync outside your script with the same usage you were using in the script, that would be... well, the *exact* same quoting you have in the script, so `"-e'ssh -p 44'"`, and would get the same results).

Comment: The `\#015` business is a clear indication that your scripts are being saved as DOS text files, not UNIX files. Use `dos2unix` to convert them, and -- in the future -- consider using a text editor that natively supports UNIX text files. (If you use `vim`, for instance, even the graphical Vim for Windows, you can run `:set fileformat=unix` to avoid DOS newline issues).

Comment: ahh i see.. that does sound promising. Thanks i will give it a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't re-group options when quoting.  Try this:

```
options=(-avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx --exclude ".idea*" --exclude "*.git*" --exclude "node-sass" -e "ssh -p 44")
src=/cygdrive/d/Work/site/
trg="john@87.87.87.87:/var/node/john.site.com/"
rsync "${options[@]}" "$src" "$trg"
```

Comment: I still get "port 22: Connection refused" when trying this :|

Comment: Then change the shebang in your script to `#! /bin/bash -x` and see how `bash` runs `rsync`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: No, the working entry does this: `-e "ssh -p 44"`.

Comment: *facepalm*. Reading comprehension fail, there.

Comment: I have now tried removing the requirement for the port number by setting it, and the ip, in an ssh config file. But i get the following error using the above ```$ bash runRsync 
rsync: link_stat "/cygdrive/d/Work/site/(-avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx)\#015" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: @John, could you show the exact code you ran that gave that result? What lcd047 has here shouldn't do that.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, I'll bet (good money, even) that the `\#015` is a LF, meaning we have DOS-format text files. That's consistent with use of cygwin.

Answer (score -2):

The subtle issue that is causing trouble is the `-e "ssh -p 44"` option. When using the `-e` or `--rsh=COMMAND`:

> Command-line arguments are permitted in COMMAND provided that COMMAND
>   is presented to rsync as a **single argument**.

Moving `-e "ssh -p 44"` out of the option string allows it to work as intended. The array approach would look like:

```
opts=( -avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx --exclude '.idea*' --exclude '*.git*' --exclude node-sass )
```

As mentioned in the comments, a single variable is not recommended from a best practices standpoint. However, you can confirm the following would also work:

```
opts='-avz --delete --chmod=ug=rwx,o=rx --exclude .idea* --exclude *.git* --exclude node-sass'
```

You can specify your source and destination any way you like:

```
src="/cygdrive/d/Work/site/"

dest="john@12.12.12.12:/var/node/john.site.com/"
```

The `rsync` call using an option array becomes:

```
rsync ${opts[@]} -e "ssh -p 44" "$src" "$dest"
```

Or, for testing purposes, you can use the single variable as follows:

```
rsync $opts -e "ssh -p 44" "$src" "$dest"
```

---

### configure `ssh` to use `port 44` for host `12.12.12.12`

**Note:** if you will be communicating with `12.12.12.12` on `port 44` on a regular basis, the it makes **much more sense** to provide a `~/.ssh/config` specification telling `ssh` (the **default** transport for `rsync`) that `12.12.12.12` communicates on `port 44`. The `HOST` `PORT` config format in `~/.ssh/config` is for example:

```
Host 12.12.12.12
Port 44
```

Create or edit the file, add the above options, and you can remove the `-e "ssh -p 44"` option completely from then on.

Comment: No, `-p 44` should be an option to `ssh`.

Comment: **double-quote** it then. I thought about it, and have used `-e ssh blah...` often and not had issues.

Comment: I get the following error with this:  runRsync: line 5: rysnc: command not found
runRsync: line 6: $'\r': command not found

Comment: @David C. Rankin: Not sure why you're shouting at me.  I'm perfectly aware what the OP should do, which is why I pointed you to a problem in your post. _shrug_

Comment: @John `typo` sorry.. I would suspect there would be an error trying to execute `rysnc` (no command like that here either `:p`)

Comment: @lcd047, not shouting, I emphasize **single** or **double** quotes to make sure it is apparent.

Comment: This is exceedingly bad practice -- **requiring** string-splitting and glob expansion rather than avoiding them.

Comment: Yes, You are correct Charles, testing has revealed error in my ways. Reforming.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, a herestring will fix it.

Comment: Yep, further test showed this is rapidly a losing battle, the array approach is superior -- nuking `:p`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, getting caught by one of these issue while in the middle of shuffling kids home from different schools is never fun... The issue hit me when picking the last up form highschool. I had never had issue with an option string because I'd never tried to include `-e ssh blah...` in the option string itself. This causes the transfer to take place in a separate shell. Attempting to bury this functionality in a string is problematic. Moving it outside the option string allows normal function. Does this fix all the issues with the approach?

Comment: Using the string-splitting approach remains awful, in a "flouts best practices, lots of caveats, no benefits" kind of way.

Comment: Somehow that is what I anticipated in a way. Then we shall nuke again and read further.

Comment: Need quotes in defining your array. `--exclude .idea* --exclude *.git*` should be `--exclude '.idea*' --exclude '*.git*'` to ensure that these patterns aren't expanded locally before being passed to rsync.

Comment: Roger, fixing. Thanks Charles!